# Else, elif, if problems in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

```
instrument=(raw_input("Which kind of tab would you like to view? Enter 'Guitar' or 'Bass' for a random tab " ))
print
if instrument=='guitar' or 'Guitar':
    print ("0-3-5---0-3-6-5---0-3-5-3-0")
elif instrument=='bass' or 'Bass':
    print ("3-5-12--12-0-5-6-0-0-0-3")
else:
    print 'Sorry, please re-enter a proper answer'
```

This code prints out the 'guitar' tab(the first if statement) every time, no matter what you type in for the variable 'instrument'.

I'm trying to teach myself python and am just jumping in and learning as I go, this is a basic program I'm working on and want to expand on.

I've looked online but from what I've read about if else statements, it looks to my novice eyes that this code should work. I'm missing something that I just can't figure out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if instrument=='guitar' or 'Guitar':
```

is parsed like

```
if (instrument=='guitar') or ('Guitar'):
```

Non-empty strings like `'Guitar'` are evaluated as `True`, so the first condition is always `True`.

Instead, use

```
if instrument in ('guitar', 'Guitar'):
```

or, if you are willing to accept funny spellings like `'gUiTAR'`, you could use

```
if instrument.lower() == 'guitar':
```

Comment: I think you mean `('guitar', 'Guitar')`.

Answer (score 7):

```
instrument == 'guitar' or 'Guitar'
```

should be

```
instrument == 'guitar' or instrument == 'Guitar'
```

or better,

```
instrument in ('guitar', 'Guitar')
```

or even

```
instrument.lower() == 'guitar'
```

and the same for the bass portion.

---

The reason why it's always outputting the first option is that `a == b or c`...

...is actually read as `(a == b) or c`.

The `or` operator is not used how you think it is. It is a logical or, not a "multiple options" separator.

Comment: That 'bible' variable actually should've been 'instrument', sorry I fixed it in my question. But your examples still stand true